# Finding the Bass-Serre tree of a given splitting over $\mathbb Z$ or $\{1\}$.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, trees

Consider an amalgam $G \ast _A H$, or an HNN extension $G \ast_A$. For simplicity, suppose that $A = \{1\}$ or $A = \mathbb Z$. I'd like to use find the Bass-Serre tree associated with such splittings. I am aware of the construction of the universal cover of a graph of groups given in Serre [1], though I am struggling to put this construction into practice and examples seem to be lacking in the literature.

As a concrete example, consider the fundamental group of a torus $G = \pi_1(S^1 \times S^1) \cong \mathbb Z^2$, split along a simple closed curve $\{z\} \times S^1$ via the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem. This represents $G$ as an HNN extension $G \cong \mathbb Z \ast_{\mathbb Z}$. My question is, how can we explicitly construct the Bass-Serre tree for this splitting?

I am working on a problem where being able to construct explicit examples of such trees will prove very helpful, so any guidance on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**References**

[1] Serre, J. P. (1980). *Trees*. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Comment: In an HNN-tree, the stable letter $t$ acts by translation while the base group $G$ permute incoming/outgoing edges of a (fixed) vertex. That is, in $G\ast_{A^t=B}$, we have a vertex with ingoing edges labelled by the cosets $G/A$ and outgoing edges labelled by $G/B$, and then $G$ acts by $gA\mapsto (hg)A$ and $gB\mapsto (hg)B$. All other vertices are conjugates of this set-up.

Comment: In your example of $\mathbb{Z}\ast_{\mathbb{Z}}$, the tree is not locally finite, so maybe a more instructive example is the Baumslag--Solitar group $\langle a, t\mid t^{-1}a^2t=a^3\rangle$, where each vertex has 2 incoming edges and 3 outgoing edges.